# Get SQL Server column names with values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, information-schema

I am trying to create a query that allows me to have the column name next to its column values that it finds.

As an example:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = 'saverTbl'
```

The above returns all of the column names in that table like this:

```
id, Link_userTblID, type, environment, vendor, theGUID, theGUID, etc etc...
```

Now what I need is to get the output from the table name next to the value. This is my query to just get my values from the table:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    saverTbl 
WHERE 
    LINK_userTblID = @val1
```

The above returns the row that matches the `LINK_userTblID` like so:

```
32, 1, 'Blah', 'something', 'Adobe', 546656156-45332-54616516-4515, etc etc..
```

Now putting that all together (which is what this question is all about):

```
id: 32,
LINK_userTblID: 1,
type: Blah,
environment: something,
vendor: Adobe,
theGUID: 546656156-45332-54616516-4515,
etc etc.....
```

Pretty much needing the output in a json format but the **column name matching up** with the **columns value**.

Comment: Pretty sure what you call "table names" are actually "column names".   In the last sentence you got it correct; not sure what you are thinking at the beginning of the post.

Comment: Do you realize there is a lot of support for JSON in sql server now? You don't want or need to do this the way you are trying to. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, this is meant for one single row you can try this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.objects FOR XML PATH('row'),TYPE) AS TheXml
)
SELECT TheElement.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')
       + ': '
       + TheElement.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS YourOutput
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY TheXml.nodes('/row/*') AS A(TheElement);
```

The result:

```
YourOutput
---------------
name: sysrscols
object_id: 3
schema_id: 4
parent_object_id: 0
type: S 
type_desc: SYSTEM_TABLE
create_date: 2012-02-10T20:15:58.693
modify_date: 2012-02-10T20:15:58.700
is_ms_shipped: 1
is_published: 0
is_schema_published: 0
```

XML in connection with `XQuery` and `XPath` is a very mighty toolset to solve rather generic problems. The cte builds an XML which looks like this:

```
<row>
  <name>sysrscols</name>
  <object_id>3</object_id>
  <schema_id>4</schema_id>
  <parent_object_id>0</parent_object_id>
  <type>S </type>
  <type_desc>SYSTEM_TABLE</type_desc>
  <create_date>2012-02-10T20:15:58.693</create_date>
  <modify_date>2012-02-10T20:15:58.700</modify_date>
  <is_ms_shipped>1</is_ms_shipped>
  <is_published>0</is_published>
  <is_schema_published>0</is_schema_published>
</row>
```

The call to `/row/*` retrieves all nodes below `<row>` as derived table. The rest is rather easy `XQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM saverTbl 
WHERE LINK_userTblID = @val1
FOR JSON PATH
```